# Python dummy function with specific amount of ram for workflow testing

Tags: python

I want to create a dummy workflow for testing a workflow managing software.

Is there a python function where I can say how much RAM it must use? So I can make multiple workflows, all needing a different amount of RAM.

Else, do you know good dummy workflows I can use?

Comment: look here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/301057/testing-my-system-i-need-a-script-that-will-use-as-much-ram-and-swap-as-possibl

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of code from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/301063/1102943

Code (python3):

```
import numpy

def take_up_ram(gigabytes):
    n = gigabytes * 1024
    result = [numpy.random.bytes(1024*1024) for x in range(n)]
    print(len(result))
```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry, fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply create any primitive type of desired size:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(bytes(1024 * 1024))
1048609
```

Note that by the nature of how Python works, no method will exactly set the memory consumption. The overhead should be roughly constant and negligible for all significant sizes, though.